# Using Mutiple Buttons at once ? Actionscript

Tags: android, actionscript-3

I am currently working on a game built using Action-script for the android phone or table and im looking for a way to hit two buttons at the same time. Or in other words pushing and holding a movement button then pushing / tapping the firing button.

This is what i have so far. it currently moves the character up and down and shoots

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var shootCheck:Boolean = false;

Shoot_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,Click);
UP_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, uparrowDown);
UP_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, uparrowUp);

DOWN_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, downarrowDown);
DOWN_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, downarrowUp);

this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, removehandle1);
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, removehandle2);

function uparrowDown(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,upEnter);
}

function upEnter(e:Event):void
{
    Player_mc.y = Player_mc.y - 10;
}
function uparrowUp(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, upEnter);
}

function downarrowDown(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,downEnter);
}
function downEnter(e:Event):void
{
    Player_mc.y = Player_mc.y + 10;
}
function downarrowUp(e:MouseEvent):void
{

    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, downEnter);
}

function removehandle1(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, upEnter);
}
function removehandle2(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, downEnter);
}

function Click(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var bull:Bullet = new Bullet();
    addChild(bull);
    bull.x = Player_mc.x + 60;
    bull.y = Player_mc.y + Player_mc.height / 4;
    var beweeg:Function = function(evt:Event)
        {
                bull.x +=  15;
        };
        bull.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,beweeg);
}
```

any help based off the limited info would be greatly appreciated and thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can build a mechanis that will get the exact time of button press by using getCurrentTimeInMillis() ,
And when the next button is pressed it takes the time again . now you can check if the time passed between the two presses is very close and if those two buttons related to a certain action you like to perform.

Comment: I know it tells us to keep an open mind but I'm sort of a 'Newb' so i have to ask how would that help the program